# Batch file to perform multiple conversions in a row

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, batch-processing, mkv

I'm trying to write a batch file that can be launched from Handbrake GUI with the "send file to" feature, that will split an MKV into chapters with MKVmerge, then convert all those new files into mp4s with ffmpeg. Handbrake passes only one argument into the batch file, the full file path of the output (surrounded by quotes). I'm very new to batch scripting and am having difficulty getting it all to work together -- all the individual parts work just fine when absolute paths are given. Here's the content of the .bat file:

```
START /WAIT "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe -o output.mkv --split chapters:all %1"
for %%i in (*.mkv) do C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%i" -loop 1 -i "%%~dpi"\folder.jpg -map 1:v -map 0:a -c:a ac3 -b:a 640K -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M "%%~ni.mp4"
```

Any glaring mistakes I'm making? I've been at this for hours reading SO threads and documentation, and can't figure it out for the life of me. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why using `start /WAIT`? it should not be necessary…

Comment: Also, you have the entire line of code you want to execute within double quotes. You only need the double quotes around the full path to the executable file you want to run.